# Service launch too many times

Tags: android, android-service

I've defined a service that is launched at the startup of the application.

I have a `Toast` in the **`onCreate`** method of the service to trace when it is launched.

All works fine but when I am in another application or in the applications list the **`onCreate`** `Toast` is displayed. It means that my service is launched, but not by my app.

My manifest looks like this:

```
    <permission
        android:name="net.test.lib.service.SERVICE_PERMISSION"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="net.test.lib.service.SERVICE_PERMISSION" />

    <application ...>

      <service
         android:name="net.test.lib.service.MyService"
         android:exported="false"
         android:permission="net.test.lib.service.SERVICE_PERMISSION" >
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="net.test.lib.service.LAUNCH_SERVICE" />
         </intent-filter>
     </service>
   </application>
```

I notice that although my service needs a permission, I can start it even if I didn't set the permission to my application.

Need help, I'm stuck...

EDIT

Here my service's code:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    private final IBinder _binder = new LocalBinder();

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public MyService getService() {
            return MyService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return _binder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Service.onCreate", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        refresh();
    }

    public void refresh(){

        [...]

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"onDestroy", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
 }
```

I can launch my service with no permission although my service needs one. Weird...

Comment: So is your issue that you only want your service to be launched when you explicitly launch your app?

Comment: Absolutely, for the moment I want to manage my service like this.

Comment: Did you add the flag `Service.START_STICKY` in your service, perhaps?

Comment: No, I didn't. Should I do it?

Comment: No, it was just a guess. I thought perhaps the system was restarting your service at some later time after it was stopped to free memory.

Comment: onDestroy is not called, I don't understand why the onCreate is called so often.

Comment: This really doesn't make sense. You shouldn't be restarting your service if you haven't declared START_STICKY. Once it dies it dies unless you are somehow restarting it from your app. What is the code for your service? Doubt it is the culprit but it may be doing something weird.

Comment: Ok I edit my question. I agree with you, it doesn't make sense. Permission seems useless...